# i want to display this small digits into this code

Tags: javascript, html, api

I want to display result with small digits.
The result of code is `ATRILCXPRICBTC   1.134916286172e-7   1.311458819577e-7`  and I want to make is look like `0.00000001`.

```
async function init() {
    const url = "https://exchange-api.lcx.com/market/tickers";
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const json = await resp.json();
    const LCXUSDCBid = json.data['LCX/USDC'].bestBid
                const BTCUSDCAsk = json.data['BTC/USDC'].bestAsk
                const BTCUSDCBid = json.data['BTC/USDC'].bestBid
                const ATRILCXBid = json.data['ATRI/LCX'].bestBid
                const ATRILCXAsk = json.data['ATRI/LCX'].bestAsk
                const ATRILCXPRICUSDCEBid = LCXUSDCBid * ATRILCXBid
                const ATRILCXPRICUSDCEAsk = LCXUSDCBid * ATRILCXAsk
                const ATRILCXPRICBTCBid = ATRILCXPRICUSDCEBid / BTCUSDCBid
                const ATRILCXPRICBTCAsk = ATRILCXPRICUSDCEAsk / BTCUSDCBid


    const tableBody = document.querySelector("#prices tbody");
    tableBody.innerHTML += `<tr>
        <td style="color:blue;">ATRILCXPRICBTC</td>
        <td style="color:green;">${ATRILCXPRICBTCBid}</td>
        <td style="color:red;">${ATRILCXPRICBTCAsk}</td>
      </tr>`;
}
init();
```

This is what I tried but it didn't work.

I want to set  to all file

Comment: Please don't just randomly mark things as block quote. Please do **stop and review your question for typos and readability** when invited to by the site before posting it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you can...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
x = 0.0000000005;

console.log(x);              // 5e-10
console.log(x.toFixed(10));  // 0.0000000005
```

Comment: work tankyou !!